# Почему не происходит рендер после изменения состояния хуком?

Tags: reactjs

Перешел на функциональные компоненты с классов и не происходит рендер после изменения состояния. Подскажите в чем проблема.

Как работало в классе:

```js
name.forEach(function(elem) {
            if (checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) === true) {
                    for (let i = 0, len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (array2[i] === elem) {
                            array2.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        });

            this.setState({
                opNames: array2,
            });
```

Как не работает в функции:

```js
name.forEach(function(elem) {
            if (checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) === true) {
                    for (let i = 0, len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (array2[i] === elem) {
                            array2.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            setOpNames(array2);
        });
```

Весь компонент:

```js
function MassViewer (props) {

    const [checkInput, setCheckInput] = useState('');
    const [opNames, setOpNames] = useState(["name1", "name2", "name3"]);

    function AddBrand (name) {
        let array = opNames;
        function checkAvailability(array, name) {
            return array.some(function(arrVal) {
                return name === arrVal;
            });
        }
        if (checkAvailability(array, name) === false) {
            setOpNames([...opNames, name]);
        } else {
            setCheckInput('Такое название уже есть');
        }

    }

    function ElementList({opNames}) {
        console.log(opNames);
        return opNames.map((name) => (
            console.log(name),
            <Operator key={name} brand={name}/>
        ));
    }

    function DeleteBrand (name) {
        let array2 = opNames;
        function checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) {
            return array2.some(function(arrVal) {
                return elem === arrVal;
            });
        }

        name.forEach(function(elem) {
            if (checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) === true) {
                    for (let i = 0, len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (array2[i] === elem) {
                            array2.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            setOpNames(array2);
        });
    }

        return (
            <div>
            <div>
                <ElementList opNames={opNames} />
            </div>
                <div>
                    <AddOperator AddBrand={AddBrand} message={checkInput}/>
                </div>
                <div><DelOperator DeleteBrand={DeleteBrand} brand={opNames} /></div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

DelOperator:

```js
export function DelOperator (props) {

const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
const [name, setName] = useState([]);
const prevNameRef = useRef([]);
useEffect(() => {
    prevNameRef.current = name;
});

function handleOpenModal () {
    setShowModal(true);
}

function handleCloseModal () {
    setShowModal(false);
}

function handleDeleteOp (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.DeleteBrand(name);
}

function checkAvailability (array, name) {
    return array.some(function(arrVal) {
        return name === arrVal;
    });
}

function checkListener (check, delOp) {
    let names = name.slice();
    const prevName = prevNameRef.current;
    console.log('До цикла: ', check, names, delOp);
    if (check === true) {
        if (checkAvailability(names, delOp) === true) {
            console.log('В цикле: ', check, names, delOp);
            for (let i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (names[i] === delOp) {
                    names.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            setName(names);
       }

        console.log('После цикла: ', check, names, delOp);

    } else if (check === false) {
        if (checkAvailability(names, delOp) === false) {
            setName([...prevName, delOp]);
        console.log('Вторая проверка: ', check, names, delOp);

        }
    } else {
            console.log('каво')
        }
    }

function CheckboxList ({brand}) {
    return brand.map((name) => (
        <CheckboxDeleteOp key={name} brand={name} checkListener={checkListener}/>
    ));
}

    return (
        <div>
            <a href="#"><span className="delOp" onClick={handleOpenModal}></span></a>
            <Modal
                closeTimeoutMS={500}
                isOpen={showModal}
                contentLabel="onRequestClose Example"
                onRequestClose={handleCloseModal}
                className="Modal"
                overlayClassName="Overlay"
            >
                <form>
                    <label className="delOpLabel">
                        <CheckboxList brand={props.brand}/>
                    </label><br />
                </form><br />
                <button onClick={handleDeleteOp}>Удалить</button><br/><br/>
                <button onClick={handleCloseModal}>Закрыть</button>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CheckboxDeleteOp:

```js
export function CheckboxDeleteOp (props) {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const prevCheckedRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        prevCheckedRef.current = !checked;
    });
    
    function handleCheck () {
        const prevChecked = prevCheckedRef.current;
        setChecked(prevChecked);
        props.checkListener(prevChecked, props.brand);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <input className="checkboxDeleteOp"
                       type="checkbox"
                       checked={checked}
                       onChange={handleCheck}/>
                <div>{props.brand}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Код всего функционального компонента прикрепите.

Comment: @xydope добавил.

Comment: DelOperator также прикрепите, т.к., если у вас не меняется состояние, то вы либо в setOpNames передаете массив без изменений, либо неправильно передаете метод DeleteBrand до конечного элемента, на котором тригерится событие. Кстати, в DeleteBrand стейт устанавливаете (setOpNames) внутри forEach.

Comment: @xydope добавил, но по вашей наводке кажется доперло, из за пуша оно не обновлялось, надо было prevState использовать. "Кстати, в DeleteBrand стейт устанавливаете (setOpNames) внутри forEach" - да, поправил.

Comment: @xydope странно, почему то такая запись не меняет массив: setName([...prevName, delOp]); Без предыдущего состояния тоже самое.

Comment: и не должен, т.к. для того, чтобы использовать prevState, нужно в setName передать callback ф-цию, setName((prevState)=>/*Что-то делаем с prevState*/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если React не перерисовывает элементы, значит вы не меняете состояние. Скорей всего, `DeleteBrand` на входе получает пустой массив (name).

Смотрите, что на входе `DeleteBrand` получаете и что в `setOpNames` устанавливаете. См. комменты ниже.

```js
function DeleteBrand (name) {
        console.log('Что получает DeleteBrand', name) // если name пустой, то ищите ошибку в методе checkListener компонента DelOperator.
        
        /*let array2 = opNames; // так, кстати, неправильно, надо делать срез исходного массива opNames.slice(). */
        let array2 = opNames.slice();
        
        console.log('Операторы', array2)
        
        //Если name не пустой, то ошибка НИЖЕ
        //эта функция зачем нужна? Делать лишний перебор? - Все, что делает ф-я - возвращает true, если в исходном массиве есть элемент.
        function checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) {
            return array2.some(function(arrVal) {
                return elem === arrVal;
            });
        }
        
        name.forEach(function(elem) {
            if (checkDelAvailability(array2, elem) === true) {
                    for (let i = 0, len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (array2[i] === elem) {
                            array2.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            /* setOpNames(array2); // setOpNames внутри forEach - ошибка. */
        });
        //Если name не пустой, то ошибка ВЫШЕ
        
        console.log('Операторы после удаления', array2)
        setOpNames(array2); //Должен быть здесь.
    }
```

Comment: В общем я конкретный затуп поймал, обновил компонент DelOperator и добавил CheckboxDeleteOp, может я даже в нем ошибку сделал. Сейчас у меня не пишутся имена в массив, либо может туда вписаться одно имя. Функция "checkDelAvailability" нужна, чтобы чистить спам чекбокса до обращения к основному массиву.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас просто чекбокс, в котором можно удалить выделенные элементы?

Comment: Да, правильно. Сейчас проснулся и на свежую голову наконец понял в чем проблема, у меня цикл не запускается видимо из за изначально пустого массива name. Пока не знаю какую проверку для этого прикрутить, но думаю догадаюсь сам, спасибо.

Comment: А, все, даже сразу доперло, нужно было просто добавить равно сюда: for (let i = 0, len = names.length; i <= len; i++)

Comment: Вы себе жизнь очень усложнили, можно все сделать проще https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-fire-qqd8u?file=/src/App.js . Читайте про методы массивов reduce, map, filter, т.к. вы сами себя путаете.

Comment: Да, так действительно красивей. Только одного не пойму, почему я получаю undefined, когда обращаюсь object.name? Сабмит хэндлер сейчас такой:

Comment: function submitHandler (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let newState = opNames.filter(({ checked }) => !checked);
        let forMap = opNames.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
        setOpNames(newState);
        console.log('Перед фильтром: ', forMap);
        let forSend = forMap.map((name) => {
            console.log('В мапе: ',name);
            setNamesToSend((prevState) => [...prevState, name.name]);
        })
        console.log(forSend);
        console.log(namesToSend);
    };

Comment: @MrYogurt Вы по 20 раз одни и те же ошибки допускаете, которые у вас кочуют из вопроса в вопрос. Учите базу JS и читайте внимательно документацию к react. А undefined вы получаете, т.к. ваш коллбек в forMap.map ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Затупил на дебаггинге с opNames, там надо было еще к индексу обратиться, а я проглядел и думал, что даже обращение сломал. Вы же писали: "чтобы использовать prevState, нужно в setName передать callback ф-цию, setName((prevState)=>/*Что-то делаем с prevState*/)". У меня все зеркально написано. Попробовал даже с хуком эффекта и рефом сделать, как в доках, но массив не собирается: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115203/discussion-between-xydope-and-mryogurt).